# Change text (or other element) color in time with Audio

Tags: html5-canvas, html5-audio, soundcloud, soundmanager2

OK, I'm designing a website for a musician who will want their tracks to be played via soundcloud (so that he can update them).

For his site I have the clients name written in the center of the page in big red writing. What I want to do is have each letter change from red to black (and back again) in time with the pulse of whatever track is being played. Not sure where to start with this project other than knowing I will probably need to use HTML5 canvas element and SoundManager2.

Thanks for your ideas and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use soundManagers eqData or peakData in combination with whileplaying to calculate the pulse effect:
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#smsound-peakdata

As you say you could do the pulse effect using canvas or go with a simple CSS text shadow.